# Available user memory (4KB pages)

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have been searching a lot for this but couldn't find concrete answer regarding this till now. This is one of the require metric from one of my customer.

How to calculate : Available user memory (4KB pages)

Is it available memory divided by 4KB? OR

Is it total memory divided by 4KB? OR

Anything else?

Comment: Have you read `/proc/meminfo`? Here's a doc from CentOS: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html. To get number of pages just divide bytes by 4096.

Comment: @EzequielGarcia: I did read but just for clarity posted this question. Thanks for the detailed link though.